# Flutter mqtt_client "MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - websocket has erred"

Tags: flutter, dart, mqtt

I'm receiving an error when connecting to my Mosquitto server in my flutter web project. I'm using the import for `mqtt_browser_client.dart` and the package  [mqtt_client](https://pub.dev/packages/mqtt_client/install).

My code follows the [example](https://github.com/shamblett/mqtt_client/blob/master/example/mqtt_server_client.dart), and I've checked, I am able to connect to my server from the same PC in MQTT Explorer. (becartpi:8080).

```
  final client = MqttBrowserClient('ws://becArtPi', 'flutter');

  void onPRessMQTTTest() async {
    client.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
    client.onConnected = onConnected;
    client.onSubscribed = onSubscribed;
    client.logging(on: true);
    client.port = 8080;
    client.keepAlivePeriod = 20;

    final connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
        .withClientIdentifier('flutter')
        .startClean() // Non persistent session for testing
        .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
    print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connecting....');
    client.connectionMessage = connMess;

    try {
      await client.connect();
    } on NoConnectionException catch (e) {
      // Raised by the client when connection fails.
      print('EXAMPLE::client exception - $e');
      client.disconnect();
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      // Raised by the socket layer
      print('EXAMPLE::socket exception - $e');
      client.disconnect();
    } catch (e) {
      print('MQTT Connection Error: $e');
    }

    client.updates!.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage?>>? c) {
      final recMess = c![0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;
      final pt =
          MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message);
      print(
          'EXAMPLE::Change notification:: topic is <${c[0].topic}>, payload is <-- $pt -->');
      print('');
    });

    /// Check we are connected
    if (client.connectionStatus!.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
      print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connected');
    } else {
      /// Use status here rather than state if you also want the broker return code.
      print(
          'EXAMPLE::ERROR Mosquitto client connection failed - disconnecting, status is ${client.connectionStatus}');
      client.disconnect();
      exit(-1);
    }
    const pubTopic = 'Dart/Mqtt_client/testtopic';
    final builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();

    client.publishMessage(pubTopic, MqttQos.exactlyOnce, builder.payload!);
  }

  void onDisconnected() {}

  void onConnected() {
    print(
        'EXAMPLE::OnConnected client callback - Client connection was sucessful');
  }

  void onSubscribed(String topic) {}
```

```
EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connecting....
1-2021-08-18 15:23:35.899 -- MqttClient::connect - keep alive is enabled with a value of 20 seconds
1-2021-08-18 15:23:35.900 -- MqttConnectionKeepAlive:: Initialised with a keep alive value of 20 seconds
1-2021-08-18 15:23:35.900 -- MqttConnectionKeepAlive:: Disconnect on no ping response is disabled
1-2021-08-18 15:23:35.901 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::connect - server ws://becArtPi/ws, port 8080
1-2021-08-18 15:23:35.901 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect entered
1-2021-08-18 15:23:35.901 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - initiating connection try 0, auto reconnect in progress false
1-2021-08-18 15:23:35.902 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - calling connect
1-2021-08-18 15:23:35.902 -- MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - entered
1-2021-08-18 15:23:35.903 -- MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect -  WS URL is ws://becartpi:8080/ws
1-2021-08-18 15:23:35.906 -- MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - connection is waiting
1-2021-08-18 15:23:36.068 -- MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - websocket has erred
1-2021-08-18 15:23:36.069 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - connection complete
1-2021-08-18 15:23:36.069 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect sending connect message
1-2021-08-18 15:23:36.069 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::sendMessage - MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connect
Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connect, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 0
Connect Variable Header: ProtocolName=MQIsdp, ProtocolVersion=3, ConnectFlags=Connect Flags: Reserved1=false, CleanStart=true, WillFlag=false, WillQos=MqttQos.atLeastOnce, WillRetain=false, PasswordFlag=false, UserNameFlag=false, KeepAlive=20
MqttConnectPayload - client identifier is : flutter
1-2021-08-18 15:23:36.072 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - pre sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
1-2021-08-18 15:23:41.098 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - post sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
1-2021-08-18 15:23:41.099 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - initiating connection try 1, auto reconnect in progress false
1-2021-08-18 15:23:41.099 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - calling connect
1-2021-08-18 15:23:41.099 -- MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - entered
1-2021-08-18 15:23:41.100 -- MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect -  WS URL is ws://becartpi:8080/ws
1-2021-08-18 15:23:41.100 -- MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - connection is waiting
1-2021-08-18 15:23:41.276 -- MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - websocket has erred
1-2021-08-18 15:23:41.276 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - connection complete
1-2021-08-18 15:23:41.276 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect sending connect message
1-2021-08-18 15:23:41.277 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::sendMessage - MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connect
Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connect, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 21
Connect Variable Header: ProtocolName=MQIsdp, ProtocolVersion=3, ConnectFlags=Connect Flags: Reserved1=false, CleanStart=true, WillFlag=false, WillQos=MqttQos.atLeastOnce, WillRetain=false, PasswordFlag=false, UserNameFlag=false, KeepAlive=20
MqttConnectPayload - client identifier is : flutter
1-2021-08-18 15:23:41.277 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - pre sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
1-2021-08-18 15:23:46.318 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - post sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
1-2021-08-18 15:23:46.318 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - initiating connection try 2, auto reconnect in progress false
1-2021-08-18 15:23:46.319 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - calling connect
1-2021-08-18 15:23:46.319 -- MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - entered
1-2021-08-18 15:23:46.319 -- MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect -  WS URL is ws://becartpi:8080/ws
1-2021-08-18 15:23:46.320 -- MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - connection is waiting
1-2021-08-18 15:23:46.487 -- MqttBrowserWsConnection::connect - websocket has erred
1-2021-08-18 15:23:46.487 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - connection complete
1-2021-08-18 15:23:46.487 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect sending connect message
1-2021-08-18 15:23:46.488 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::sendMessage - MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connect
Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connect, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 21
Connect Variable Header: ProtocolName=MQIsdp, ProtocolVersion=3, ConnectFlags=Connect Flags: Reserved1=false, CleanStart=true, WillFlag=false, WillQos=MqttQos.atLeastOnce, WillRetain=false, PasswordFlag=false, UserNameFlag=false, KeepAlive=20
MqttConnectPayload - client identifier is : flutter
1-2021-08-18 15:23:46.488 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - pre sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
1-2021-08-18 15:23:51.521 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - post sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
1-2021-08-18 15:23:51.522 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect failed
EXAMPLE::client exception - mqtt-client::NoConnectionException: The maximum allowed connection attempts ({3}) were exceeded. The broker is not responding to the connection request message (Missing Connection Acknowledgement?
1-2021-08-18 15:23:51.523 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::disconnect - entered
1-2021-08-18 15:23:51.523 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_performConnectionDisconnect entered
```

Connection in MQTT Explorer which is connecting and receiving messages correctly.
[image]

mosquitto.log

```
1629283989: Socket error on client 8caab5860e74, disconnecting.
1629284712: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1629284717: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1629284722: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

Comment: What is in the mosquitto logs for the same period?

Comment: @hardillb Super unhandy... ```1629284722: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the websocket headers API setting you may be sending the wrong headers for your broker.

Have a look at the mqtt_server_client_websocket.dart file in the examples directory, the setting you want is client.websocketProtocols, look at the API for this.

Comment: Thanks @user2685314. I've reviewed the API, and am none the wiser about how I would do this, or what my options are.

Comment: The solution was indeed to define a websocket protocol: ```client.websocketProtocols = ['mqtt'];```

Comment: this post really helps